# JAVA: An error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to get data from db, but i have this:
***You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order orderentit0_' at line 1***.

I have no idea

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
>
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java?
>       useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
>       spring.jpa.show-sql=true
>       spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
>       spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
>       spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

There are *Entity* code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order", schema = "java", catalog = "")
public class OrderEntity {
    private int orderId;
    private int clientId;
    private int roomId;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private int cost;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "orderId")
    public int getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "clientId")
    public int getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(int clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "roomId")
    public int getRoomId() {
        return roomId;
    }

    public void setRoomId(int roomId) {
        this.roomId = roomId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "end_date")
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "cost")
    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        OrderEntity that = (OrderEntity) o;

        if (orderId != that.orderId) return false;
        if (clientId != that.clientId) return false;
        if (roomId != that.roomId) return false;
        if (cost != that.cost) return false;
        if (startDate != null ? !startDate.equals(that.startDate) : that.startDate != null) return false;
        if (endDate != null ? !endDate.equals(that.endDate) : that.endDate != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = orderId;
        result = 31 * result + clientId;
        result = 31 * result + roomId;
        result = 31 * result + (startDate != null ? startDate.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (endDate != null ? endDate.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + cost;
        return result;
    }

}
```

*interface* Repository

```
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<OrderEntity, Integer> {

List<OrderEntity> findAll();

OrderEntity findOrderEntityByOrderId(int orderId);

OrderEntity findOrderEntityByStartDate(Date startDate);

OrderEntity findOrderEntityByEndDate(Date endDate);

OrderEntity findOrderEntityByClientId(int clientId);

OrderEntity findOrderEntityByRoomId(int roomId);

OrderEntity findOrderEntityByCost(int cost);

OrderEntity save(OrderEntity orderEntity);}
```

Service interface.

```
public interface OrderService {


List<OrderEntity> findAll();

OrderEntity findOrderEntityByOrderId(int orderId);

OrderEntity findOrderEntityByStartDate(Date startDate);

OrderEntity findOrderEntityByEndDate(Date endDate);

OrderEntity findOrderEntityByClientId(int clientId);

OrderEntity findOrderEntityByRoomId(int roomId);

OrderEntity findOrderEntityByCost(int cost);

OrderEntity save(OrderEntity orderEntity);
}
```

Database:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema java
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `java` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ;
USE `java` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `java`.`client`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `java`.`client` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `java`.`client` (
  `clientId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(46) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`clientId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `java`.`hotel`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `java`.`hotel` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `java`.`hotel` (
  `hotelId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `stars` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hotelId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `java`.`room`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `java`.`room` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `java`.`room` (
  `roomId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `hotelId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `beds` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `cost` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`roomId`),
  CONSTRAINT `id_hotel`
    FOREIGN KEY (`hotelId`)
    REFERENCES `java`.`hotel` (`hotelId`)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE INDEX `id_hotel_idx` ON `java`.`room` (`hotelId` ASC) VISIBLE;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `java`.`order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `java`.`order` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `java`.`order` (
  `orderId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `clientId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `roomId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `end_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `cost` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderId`),
  CONSTRAINT `clientId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clientId`)
    REFERENCES `java`.`client` (`clientId`),
  CONSTRAINT `roomId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`roomId`)
    REFERENCES `java`.`room` (`roomId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE INDEX `roomId` ON `java`.`order` (`roomId` ASC) VISIBLE;

CREATE INDEX `clientId` ON `java`.`order` (`clientId` ASC) VISIBLE;
```

Comment: please show OrderEntity and the generated SQL instead of Controller and service

Comment: @Jens It is done

Comment: `order` is a reserved keyword, so do not call your table order!!

Comment: @Jens Now it is 'orders', but problem not solved

Comment: Have you also changed @Table(name = "order" ? can you show the new error message?

Comment: @Jens Now it is 'orders', yes. Problem: Unknown column 'ordersenti0_.order_id' in 'field list' but i have no such column

Comment: As i know camelCase will set to column name `order_id`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/snekse/b12e6bfb283f269b30caa9159ff56a24

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

**It helped**